# For any natural number $n$, Prove that $\prod^{n}_{r=1}\bigg(r+\frac{1}{n}\bigg)\leq 2(n!)$

Tags: inequality

> For any natural number $n$, Prove that $$\displaystyle \prod^{n}_{r=1}\bigg(r+\frac{1}{n}\bigg)\leq 2(n!)$$

Trial Solution: Using $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n}\leq 1,2,3,\cdots n$

$\displaystyle \prod^{n}_{r=1}\bigg(1+\frac{2}{n}\bigg)\leq 2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdots \cdots 2n$

$$\prod^{n}_{r=1}\bigg(1+\frac{2}{n}\bigg)\leq 2^n\cdot n!$$

Could some help me how to prove my original inequality, Thanks

Comment: This is not at all a genuine try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can verify directly for $n=1,2$. Suppose $n\geq3$. Then
$$
  \sum_{r=1}^n\log\left(1+\frac1{rn}\right)
    \leq\sum_{r=1}^n\frac1{rn}
    \leq\frac{1+1/2+(n-2)/3}{n}
    \leq\frac{11}{18}<\log 2.
$$
Now exponentiate and multiply by $n!$.

Comment: @Riemann:  I went ahead and approved your edit, but it's the sort of correction that would be better handled by a Comment to the OP.  After all the Answer was only posted an hour ago.

Answer (score 1):

It is "easy" to show it at least for large values of $n$.
$$\prod^{n}_{r=1}\bigg(r+\frac{1}{n}\bigg)=\left(\frac{1}{n}+1\right)_n$$ where appears Pochammer symbol.

Using asymptotics,
$$\log \left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)_n\right)=n (\log (n)-1)+\frac{1}{2} \left(\log (2 \pi )+\log
   \left({n}\right)\right)+\frac{\log \left({n}\right)+\gamma
   +\frac{1}{12}}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)$$ while, using Stirling approximation, $$ \log(2(n!))=n (\log (n)-1)+\left(\log \left(2 \sqrt{2 \pi }\right)+\frac{1}{2} \log
   \left({n}\right)\right)+\frac{1}{12
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)$$ making 
$$\log \left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)_n\right)-\log(2(n!))=-\log (2)+\frac{\gamma +\log
   \left({n}\right)}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)$$ which is negative $\,\,\forall n$.